# Online Face Recognition using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement online face recognition using the webcam. I am using this two websites as references

[shervinemami.co.cc](http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/faceRecognition.html#recognizeFace)
[cognotics.com](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/page_3.html)

I have few questions:

In face recognition, there are 6 steps:

1. Grab a frame from the camera
2. Detect a face within the image
3. Crop the frame to show just the face
4. Convert the frame to greyscale
5. Preprocess the image
6. Recognize the person in the image.

I am able to do the first five steps. Last step i am not able to do. I am not sure how to  link step 5 to step 6.

I have already created the train.txt file and test.txt file which contains the information of the training and testing images. I have already added the functions such as learn(), doPCA() to the code...

But the point is how to use these functions in the main to recognize the image that is already preprocessed.

Need some help on it...

Attached the code below:

```
// Real-time.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cvaux.h>

IplImage ** faceImgArr        = 0; // array of face images
CvMat    *  personNumTruthMat = 0; // array of person numbers
int nTrainFaces               = 0; // the number of training images
int nEigens                   = 0; // the number of eigenvalues
IplImage * pAvgTrainImg       = 0; // the average image
IplImage ** eigenVectArr      = 0; // eigenvectors
CvMat * eigenValMat           = 0; // eigenvalues
CvMat * projectedTrainFaceMat = 0; // projected training faces


IplImage* getCameraFrame(CvCapture* &camera);
IplImage* detectFaces( IplImage *img ,CvHaarClassifierCascade* facecascade,CvMemStorage* storage );
CvRect detectFaceInImage(IplImage *inputImg, CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade);
IplImage* preprocess( IplImage* inputImg);
IplImage* resizeImage(const IplImage *origImg, int newWidth,
    int newHeight, bool keepAspectRatio);
void learn();
void recognize();
void doPCA();
void storeTrainingData();
int  loadTrainingData(CvMat ** pTrainPersonNumMat);
int  findNearestNeighbor(float * projectedTestFace);
int  loadFaceImgArray(char * filename);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CvCapture* camera = 0;  // The camera device.
    CvMemStorage            *storage;
    cvNamedWindow( "Realtime:", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    char *faceCascadeFilename = "C:/OpenCV2.1/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    CvHaarClassifierCascade* faceCascade;
    faceCascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad(faceCascadeFilename, 0, 0, 0);
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );

    learn();

    while ( cvWaitKey(10) != 27 )   // Quit on "Escape" key
        {   
        IplImage *frame = getCameraFrame(camera);
        //IplImage* resized=cvCreateImage(cvSize(420,240),frame->depth,3);
        //cvResizeWindow( "Image:", 640, 480);
        //cvResize(frame,resized);
        //cvShowImage( "Realtime:", resized );
        IplImage *imgA = resizeImage(frame, 420,240, true);
        IplImage *frame1 = detectFaces(imgA,faceCascade,storage);
        frame1 = preprocess(frame1);
        }   
    // Free the camera.
    cvReleaseCapture( &camera );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
    return 0;
}

IplImage* getCameraFrame(CvCapture* &camera)
{
    IplImage *frame;
    int w, h;

    // If the camera hasn't been initialized, then open it.
    if (!camera) {
        printf("Acessing the camera ...\n");
        camera = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
        if (!camera) {
            printf("Couldn't access the camera.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Try to set the camera resolution to 320 x 240.
        cvSetCaptureProperty(camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
        cvSetCaptureProperty(camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
        // Get the first frame, to make sure the camera is initialized.
        frame = cvQueryFrame( camera );
        if (frame) {
            w = frame->width;
            h = frame->height;
            printf("Got the camera at %dx%d resolution.\n", w, h);
        }
        // Wait a little, so that the camera can auto-adjust its brightness.
        Sleep(1000);    // (in milliseconds)
    }

    // Wait until the next camera frame is ready, then grab it.
    frame = cvQueryFrame( camera );
    if (!frame) {
        printf("Couldn't grab a camera frame.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return frame;
}

CvRect detectFaceInImage(IplImage *inputImg, CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade)
{
    // Smallest face size.
    CvSize minFeatureSize = cvSize(20, 20);
    // Only search for 1 face.
    int flags = CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;
    // How detailed should the search be.
    float search_scale_factor = 1.1f;
    IplImage *detectImg;
    IplImage *greyImg = 0;
    CvMemStorage* storage;
    CvRect rc;
    double t;
    CvSeq* rects;
    CvSize size;
    int i, ms, nFaces;

    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );


    // If the image is color, use a greyscale copy of the image.
    detectImg = (IplImage*)inputImg;
    if (inputImg->nChannels > 1) {
        size = cvSize(inputImg->width, inputImg->height);
        greyImg = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
        cvCvtColor( inputImg, greyImg, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        detectImg = greyImg;    // Use the greyscale image.
    }

    // Detect all the faces in the greyscale image.
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    rects = cvHaarDetectObjects( detectImg, cascade, storage,
            search_scale_factor, 3, flags, minFeatureSize);
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    ms = cvRound( t / ((double)cvGetTickFrequency() * 1000.0) );
    nFaces = rects->total;
    printf("Face Detection took %d ms and found %d objects\n", ms, nFaces);

    // Get the first detected face (the biggest).
    if (nFaces > 0)
        rc = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( rects, 0 );
    else
        rc = cvRect(-1,-1,-1,-1);   // Couldn't find the face.

    if (greyImg)
        cvReleaseImage( &greyImg );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
    //cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );

    return rc;  // Return the biggest face found, or (-1,-1,-1,-1).
}

IplImage* detectFaces( IplImage *img ,CvHaarClassifierCascade* facecascade,CvMemStorage* storage )
{
    int i;
    CvRect *r;
    CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
            img,
            facecascade,
            storage,
            1.1,
            3,
            0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
            cvSize( 40, 40 ) );

    int padding_width = 30; // pixels
    int padding_height = 30; // pixels

    for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
        r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
        cvRectangle( img,
                     cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                     cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                     CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );
    }

    cvShowImage( "Realtime:", img );

    //cropping the face
    cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(r->x,r->y,r->width,r->height));
    IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 
                            img->depth, 
                              img->nChannels);
    cvCopy(img, img2, NULL);
    cvResetImageROI(img);

    return img;
}

IplImage* preprocess( IplImage* inputImg){
    IplImage *detectImg, *greyImg = 0;
    IplImage *imageProcessed;
    CvSize size;
    detectImg = (IplImage*)inputImg;
    if (inputImg->nChannels > 1) {
        size = cvSize(inputImg->width, inputImg->height);
        greyImg = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
        cvCvtColor( inputImg, greyImg, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        detectImg = greyImg;    // Use the greyscale image.
    }

    imageProcessed = cvCreateImage(cvSize(inputImg->width, inputImg->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvResize(detectImg, imageProcessed, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    cvEqualizeHist(imageProcessed, imageProcessed);
    return imageProcessed;
}

IplImage* resizeImage(const IplImage *origImg, int newWidth,
    int newHeight, bool keepAspectRatio)
{
    IplImage *outImg = 0;
    int origWidth;
    int origHeight;
    if (origImg) {
        origWidth = origImg->width;
        origHeight = origImg->height;
    }
    if (newWidth <= 0 || newHeight <= 0 || origImg == 0
        || origWidth <= 0 || origHeight <= 0) {
        //cerr << "ERROR: Bad desired image size of " << newWidth
        //  << "x" << newHeight << " in resizeImage().\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (keepAspectRatio) {
        // Resize the image without changing its aspect ratio,
        // by cropping off the edges and enlarging the middle section.
        CvRect r;
        // input aspect ratio
        float origAspect = (origWidth / (float)origHeight);
        // output aspect ratio
        float newAspect = (newWidth / (float)newHeight);
        // crop width to be origHeight * newAspect
        if (origAspect > newAspect) {
            int tw = (origHeight * newWidth) / newHeight;
            r = cvRect((origWidth - tw)/2, 0, tw, origHeight);
        }
        else {  // crop height to be origWidth / newAspect
            int th = (origWidth * newHeight) / newWidth;
            r = cvRect(0, (origHeight - th)/2, origWidth, th);
        }
        IplImage *croppedImg = cropImage(origImg, r);

        // Call this function again, with the new aspect ratio image.
        // Will do a scaled image resize with the correct aspect ratio.
        outImg = resizeImage(croppedImg, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        cvReleaseImage( &croppedImg );

    }
    else {

        // Scale the image to the new dimensions,
        // even if the aspect ratio will be changed.
        outImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(newWidth, newHeight),
            origImg->depth, origImg->nChannels);
        if (newWidth > origImg->width && newHeight > origImg->height) {
            // Make the image larger
            cvResetImageROI((IplImage*)origImg);
            // CV_INTER_LINEAR: good at enlarging.
            // CV_INTER_CUBIC: good at enlarging.           
            cvResize(origImg, outImg, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        }
        else {
            // Make the image smaller
            cvResetImageROI((IplImage*)origImg);
            // CV_INTER_AREA: good at shrinking (decimation) only.
            cvResize(origImg, outImg, CV_INTER_AREA);
        }

    }
    return outImg;
}

void learn()
{
    int i, offset;

    // load training data
    nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/50_images_of_15_people.txt");
    if( nTrainFaces < 2 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);
        return;
    }

    // do PCA on the training faces
    doPCA();

    // project the training images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTrainFaceMat = cvCreateMat( nTrainFaces, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );
    offset = projectedTrainFaceMat->step / sizeof(float);
    for(i=0; i<nTrainFaces; i++)
    {
        //int offset = i * nEigens;
        cvEigenDecomposite(
            faceImgArr[i],
            nEigens,
            eigenVectArr,
            0, 0,
            pAvgTrainImg,
            //projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*nEigens);
            projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*offset);
    }

    // store the recognition data as an xml file
    storeTrainingData();
}

void recognize()
{
    int i, nTestFaces  = 0;         // the number of test images
    CvMat * trainPersonNumMat = 0;  // the person numbers during training
    float * projectedTestFace = 0;

    // load test images and ground truth for person number
    nTestFaces = loadFaceImgArray("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/OpenCV/test.txt");
    printf("%d test faces loaded\n", nTestFaces);

    // load the saved training data
    if( !loadTrainingData( &trainPersonNumMat ) ) return;

    // project the test images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTestFace = (float *)cvAlloc( nEigens*sizeof(float) );
    for(i=0; i<nTestFaces; i++)
    {
        int iNearest, nearest, truth;

        // project the test image onto the PCA subspace
        cvEigenDecomposite(
            faceImgArr[i],
            nEigens,
            eigenVectArr,
            0, 0,
            pAvgTrainImg,
            projectedTestFace);

        iNearest = findNearestNeighbor(projectedTestFace);
        truth    = personNumTruthMat->data.i[i];
        nearest  = trainPersonNumMat->data.i[iNearest];

        printf("nearest = %d, Truth = %d\n", nearest, truth);
    }
}

int loadTrainingData(CvMat ** pTrainPersonNumMat)
{
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
    int i;

    // create a file-storage interface
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
    if( !fileStorage )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open facedata.xml\n");
        return 0;
    }

    nEigens = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nEigens", 0);
    nTrainFaces = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nTrainFaces", 0);
    *pTrainPersonNumMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "trainPersonNumMat", 0);
    eigenValMat  = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "eigenValMat", 0);
    projectedTrainFaceMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "projectedTrainFaceMat", 0);
    pAvgTrainImg = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "avgTrainImg", 0);
    eigenVectArr = (IplImage **)cvAlloc(nTrainFaces*sizeof(IplImage *));
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
    {
        char varname[200];
        sprintf( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
        eigenVectArr[i] = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, varname, 0);
    }

    // release the file-storage interface
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );

    return 1;
}

void storeTrainingData()
{
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
    int i;

    // create a file-storage interface
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

    // store all the data
    cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nEigens", nEigens );
    cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nTrainFaces", nTrainFaces );
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "trainPersonNumMat", personNumTruthMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "eigenValMat", eigenValMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "projectedTrainFaceMat", projectedTrainFaceMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "avgTrainImg", pAvgTrainImg, cvAttrList(0,0));
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
    {
        char varname[200];
        sprintf( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
        cvWrite(fileStorage, varname, eigenVectArr[i], cvAttrList(0,0));
    }

    // release the file-storage interface
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );
}

int findNearestNeighbor(float * projectedTestFace)
{
    //double leastDistSq = 1e12;
    double leastDistSq = DBL_MAX;
    int i, iTrain, iNearest = 0;

    for(iTrain=0; iTrain<nTrainFaces; iTrain++)
    {
        double distSq=0;

        for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        {
            float d_i =
                projectedTestFace[i] -
                projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];
            //distSq += d_i*d_i / eigenValMat->data.fl[i];  // Mahalanobis
            distSq += d_i*d_i; // Euclidean
        }

        if(distSq < leastDistSq)
        {
            leastDistSq = distSq;
            iNearest = iTrain;
        }
    }

    return iNearest;
}

void doPCA()
{
    int i;
    CvTermCriteria calcLimit;
    CvSize faceImgSize;

    // set the number of eigenvalues to use
    nEigens = nTrainFaces-1;

    // allocate the eigenvector images
    faceImgSize.width  = faceImgArr[0]->width;
    faceImgSize.height = faceImgArr[0]->height;
    eigenVectArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(sizeof(IplImage*) * nEigens);
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        eigenVectArr[i] = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // allocate the eigenvalue array
    eigenValMat = cvCreateMat( 1, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );

    // allocate the averaged image
    pAvgTrainImg = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // set the PCA termination criterion
    calcLimit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, nEigens, 1);

    // compute average image, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
    cvCalcEigenObjects(
        nTrainFaces,
        (void*)faceImgArr,
        (void*)eigenVectArr,
        CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK,
        0,
        0,
        &calcLimit,
        pAvgTrainImg,
        eigenValMat->data.fl);

    cvNormalize(eigenValMat, eigenValMat, 1, 0, CV_L1, 0);
}

int loadFaceImgArray(char * filename)
{
    FILE * imgListFile = 0;
    char imgFilename[512];
    int iFace, nFaces=0;


    // open the input file
    if( !(imgListFile = fopen(filename, "r")) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can\'t open file %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    // count the number of faces
    while( fgets(imgFilename, 512, imgListFile) ) ++nFaces;
    rewind(imgListFile);

    // allocate the face-image array and person number matrix
    faceImgArr        = (IplImage **)cvAlloc( nFaces*sizeof(IplImage *) );
    personNumTruthMat = cvCreateMat( 1, nFaces, CV_32SC1 );

    // store the face images in an array
    for(iFace=0; iFace<nFaces; iFace++)
    {
        // read person number and name of image file
        fscanf(imgListFile,
            "%d %s", personNumTruthMat->data.i+iFace, imgFilename);

        // load the face image
        faceImgArr[iFace] = cvLoadImage(imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if( !faceImgArr[iFace] )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can\'t load image from %s\n", imgFilename);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(imgListFile);

    return nFaces;
}
```

Comment: You have asked a fairly vague question "Find difficulty in doing in linking step 5 to step 6.", and have posted a lot of code. To improve your chances of getting a good answer, consider posting only relevant sections of the code, after explaining the method you are trying to use to recognise the faces.

Answer (score 0):

I just read

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
.......
}
```

part of your code. This code is used for detecting the face in the image. Lets say it is `Face_x`. Now extract features from `Face_x`, call it as `F_x`. In your database, you should store features `{F_1, F_2,..., F_N}` extracted from `n` different faces `{Face_1, Face_2,..Face_N}`.

Simple algorithm to recognize `Face_x` is to calculate Euclidean distances between `F_x` and `n` features. The minimum distance (below threshold) gives corresponding face. If the minimum distance is not below threshold then `Face_x` is a new face. Add feature `F_x` to database. This way you can increase your database. You can begin your algorithm with no features in database. With each new face, database grows.
I hope the method suggested by me will lead you to the solution

Answer (score 0):

My answer may came late but it might be useful for pals if i answer it.I am working on a similar project and i have faced the same problem.I solved it by writing a function the saves or write the detected,cropped and preprocessed image on to the hard disk of my computer(Using CvWrite).And feeding the parameter of the saved images to the recognition part of the code. It has made my life easier.It has been a bit harder for me to to pass the parameters of the rect of the region of interest. If you or someone else did this it might be great sharing the code with us. 
     You can use the following code to save the image after resizing it to a constant value using the resizeimage function on you code.

```
    void saveCroppedFaces(CvSeq* tempon,IplImage* DetectedImage)
{

        char* name;
        int nFaces;
        CvRect rect;
        nFaces=tempon->total;
        name =new char[nFaces];
        IplImage* cropped = 0;
        IplImage* croppedResized=0;
        Mat croped;
        for(int k=0;k<nFaces;k++)
        {
            itoa(k,(name+k),10);
            rect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( tempon, k );
            cropped= cropImage(DetectedImage,rect);
            //i can resize the cropped faces in to a fixed size here

            //i can write a function to save images and call it so
                  //that it will save it in to hard drive 
            //cvNamedWindow((name+k),CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

            //cvShowImage((name+k),cropped);
            croppedResized=resizeImage(cropped,60,60);
            croped=IplToMatConverter(croppedResized);
            saveROI(croped,itoa(k,(name+k),10));
            cvReleaseImage(&cropped);
        }
    name=NULL;
    delete[] name;

}

void saveROI(Mat mat,String outputFileName)
{
    string store_path("C://Users/sizusuzu/Desktop/Images/FaceDetection2
                                                    /"+outputFileName+".jpg");
    bool write_success = imwrite(store_path,mat);

}
```

After this you can change the IplImage* to Mat using

```
      Mat IplToMatConverter(IplImage* imageToMat)
     {
    Mat mat = cvarrToMat(imageToMat);
    return mat;
     }
```

And use the Mat in FaceRecognizer API.Or just do the other/harder way.
Thanks