# Unhandled exception at 0x00cd2e34 in Detect.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opencv, access-violation, face-recognition

I'm trying to train 7 text files which will generate 7 xml files as the output. Hence i tried through a "for loop" which will function 7 times.

I have referred the following link for face recognition
[Online Face Recognition using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504216/online-face-recognition-using-opencv)

I'm getting an error when running the code:
Unhandled exception at 0x00cd2e34 in Detect.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Appreciate your support in this regard. Thanks!

Code related to the error and for loop:

```
void learn() {
    int offset;
    for(int i=0; i<=7; i++){
        if (i==1){
            //first text file
            // load training data from Diamond.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Diamond.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }

        if (i==2){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Heart.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Heart.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }

        if (i==3){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Square.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Square.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }   

        if (i==4){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Oblong.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Oblong.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }

        if (i==5){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Oval.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Oval.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }

        if (i==6){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Round.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Round.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }

        if (i==7){
            //the next text file
            // load training data from Triangle.txt
            nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("Triangle.txt");
            if( nTrainFaces <2 )
            {

                fprintf(stderr,
                "Need 2 or more training faces\n"
                "Input file contains only %d\n", nTrainFaces);

                return;
            }
        }


        // do PCA on the training faces
        doPCA();

        // project the training images onto the PCA subspace                        
        projectedTrainFaceMat = cvCreateMat( nTrainFaces, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );
        offset = projectedTrainFaceMat->step / sizeof(float);
        for(int i=0; i<nTrainFaces; i++)
        {
            //int offset = i * nEigens;
            cvEigenDecomposite(
            faceImgArr[i],
            nEigens,
            eigenVectArr,
            0, 0,
            pAvgTrainImg,
            //projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*nEigens);
            projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*offset);
        }
        // store the recognition data as an xml file
        storeTrainingData();
    }
}


void doPCA() {
    int i;
    faceImgArr        = 0;
    CvTermCriteria calcLimit;
    CvSize faceImgSize;

    // set the number of eigenvalues to use
    nEigens = nTrainFaces-1;

    // allocate the eigenvector images
    faceImgSize.width  = faceImgArr[0]->width; // I GET THE ERROR HERE 
    faceImgSize.height = faceImgArr[0]->height;
    eigenVectArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(sizeof(IplImage*) * nEigens);
    for(i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
    eigenVectArr[i] = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // allocate the eigenvalue array
    eigenValMat = cvCreateMat( 1, nEigens, CV_32FC1 );

    // allocate the averaged image
    pAvgTrainImg = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    // set the PCA termination criterion
    calcLimit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, nEigens, 1);

    // compute average image, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
    cvCalcEigenObjects(
    nTrainFaces,
    (void*)faceImgArr,
    (void*)eigenVectArr,
    CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK,
    0,
    0,
    &calcLimit,
    pAvgTrainImg,
    eigenValMat->data.fl);

    cvNormalize(eigenValMat, eigenValMat, 1, 0, CV_L1, 0);
}

void storeTrainingData() {
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
        CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
        if (i==1){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Diamond.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }

        if (i==2){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Heart.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }


        if (i==3){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Square.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }

        if (i==4){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Oblong.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }

        if (i==5){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Oval.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }

        if (i==6){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Round.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }
        if (i==7){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Triangle.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

        }


        // store all the data
        cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nEigens", nEigens );
        cvWriteInt( fileStorage, "nTrainFaces", nTrainFaces );
        cvWrite(fileStorage, "trainPersonNumMat", personNumTruthMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
        cvWrite(fileStorage, "eigenValMat", eigenValMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
        cvWrite(fileStorage, "projectedTrainFaceMat", projectedTrainFaceMat, cvAttrList(0,0));
        cvWrite(fileStorage, "avgTrainImg", pAvgTrainImg, cvAttrList(0,0));
        for(int i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        {
            char varname[200];
            sprintf( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
            cvWrite(fileStorage, varname, eigenVectArr[i], cvAttrList(0,0));
        }

        // release the file-storage interface
        cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );

    }
}

int loadTrainingData(CvMat ** pTrainPersonNumMat) {
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;

    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
        if (i==1){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Diamond.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (i==2){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Heart.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (i==3){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Square.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (i==4){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Oblong.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (i==5){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Oval.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (i==6){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Square.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }

        }

        if (i==7){
            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "Triangle.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
            if( !fileStorage )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open Diamond.xml\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }


        nEigens = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nEigens", 0);
        nTrainFaces = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage, 0, "nTrainFaces", 0);
        *pTrainPersonNumMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "trainPersonNumMat", 0);
        eigenValMat  = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "eigenValMat", 0);
        projectedTrainFaceMat = (CvMat *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "projectedTrainFaceMat", 0);
        pAvgTrainImg = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, "avgTrainImg", 0);
        eigenVectArr = (IplImage **)cvAlloc(nTrainFaces*sizeof(IplImage *));
        for(int i=0; i<nEigens; i++)
        {
            char varname[200];
            sprintf( varname, "eigenVect_%d", i );
            eigenVectArr[i] = (IplImage *)cvReadByName(fileStorage, 0, varname, 0);
        }

        // release the file-storage interface
        cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop is pointless; you're still repeating yourself for each iteration.  You may as well delete the loop (or, better yet, understand them and store your file names in some sort of collection, iterating over that.)

Comment: Your loop crashs when i==0 because fileStorage won't be assigned.

Comment: I would recommend using a debugger to step through your code (or minimally inserting print statements) to help narrow down where the crash is happening. Just posting a big blob of incomplete code like this not likely to yield useful answers. Albeit a big blob, potentially relevant pieces of code such as some variable definitions are not included. nTrainFaces is not defined for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop inside of storeTrainingData will cause a crash because when i==0, no files will be opened, and yet you call the cvWriteInt on an empty handle.

This should fix it:

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++)
```

Although in thinking about this, it is still kind of inefficient.

I think you need to study up on starting at zero instead of 1, indexing things, etc.

There is way too much code duplication here.